# Parameterize the Loop in selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to parametrize the following code each time a new i value it has to take how to pass the i value.

```
   for(int i=1 ; i<6; i++ )
     {
greeting[i] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@width=\"270\"]/tbody/tr[i]/td")).getText(); System.out.println(""+greeting[i]);  }
```

i want each time

```
greeting[1] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@width=\"270\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td")).getText(); System.out.println(""+greeting[1]);
```

like so on,

Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use String's format method for this. define a variable like

`String xpath = "//table[@width=\"270\"]/tbody/tr[%s]/td";` as a template before the loop
Then in the for loop use

```
String xpathOfElement = String.format(xpath, String.valueOf(i));
```

However ideally you have to wait for elements before getting their properties.